# replace all files with same name

Tags: macos, window

I have a file in multiple folder called  PFSound.js 
I've updated it so I want to replace all PFSound.js files in those directories for the new one,

is there a way to do it in just one time?

Mac or windows is ok

Thanks!!

Comment: This seems to be a system administrator question, rather than a programming question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Mac/Linux, you can do this:

```
find . -type f -name "PFSound.js" -exec cp path/to/new/PFSound.js {} \;
```

assuming you wish to do that from the current directory downwards and that the new PFSound.js is located somewhere else.

That says.... find, starting at dot (the current directory) all things of type "file" with the name "PFSound.js", and for each one you find, execute the copy command and copy the new PFSound.js into the same place you just found an old one.

Answer (score 1):

you can use a python script for this .

```
import os 
newfilename="the_new_name"
def renamethefile(folderPath):
    for fileOrFolder in os.listdir(folderPath):
        if os.path.isdir(fileOrFolder) :
            renamethefile(fileOrFolder)
            continue
        else:
            os.rename(fileOrFolder, newfilename) 
renamethefile("/path/to/the/folder");
```

i hope this help you .